# How to databind a dropdownlist using knockout and MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, knockout.js

I have two cascading dropdownlists which I would like to bind based on my knockout.js. Essentially what I want to achieve is two dropdownlist that populate from a database for each branch of the company and one which will populate the various departments based on the branch that was selected in the other dropdownlist. I am having problems converting to a list and then binding to dropdownlist.

```
function CompanyViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.DepartmentName = ko.observable(" ")
    self.Department =ko.observableArray([]);
    self.DepartmentName = ko.Observable([]);
    self.Branch =ko.observableArray([]);
    self.BranchName = ko.Observable([])
}
CompanyViewModel = new CompanyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(CompanyViewModel);


function  populateCompanyBranches() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        $.when(getSecureData("/api/Branches/" ))
        .done(function (Branches) {
            Branch.unshift({ "BranchID": 0, "department name": "Please select a Branch." });
            CompanyViewModel.Branch(Branch);
        })
        .fail(function (message) {
            $.msgbox(message);
        });
};



function populateBranchDepartments() {
    $("#Branches").change(function () {
                var BranchID = $("#Branches").val();                           
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
          $.when(getSecureData("/api/Departments/GetDepartment" + BranchID))
        .done(function (Department) {
        CompanyDepartment.unshift({ "CompanyID": 0, "departmentName": "Please select a department" });
            CompanyViewModel.Department(Department);
        })
        .fail(function (message) {
            $.msgbox(message);
            });
        };
}
```

View

```
Branch Name: <select data-bind="options:  CompanyViewModel. CompanyViewModel, optionsCaption: 'Select a Branch',
    optionsValue: function (item) { return item.BranchId; },
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.BranchName; }, value: Branch,
    valueUpdate: 'change'" id="Branches" name="Branch"></select>
<br />

Deaprtment Name: <select data-bind="options: CompanyViewModel.Department, optionsCaption: 'Choose Department...',
    optionsValue: function (item) { return item.DepartmentId; },
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.DepartmentName; },  value: DepartmentName,
    valueUpdate: 'change'" id="Department" name="Department"></select>
<br />   
  </div>

public class CompanyDTO
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set;}  
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set;}  
}

public static class CompanyBranchList
{
    public static CompanyDTO DepartmentToBranchDTO(listing e)
    {
        return new CompanyDTO 
        {
            BranchId = e.BranchId,
            BranchName = e.BranchName
            DepartmentId = e.DepartmentId
            DepartmentName = e.DepartmentName

        };
    }


    public static List<CompanyDTO> ListBranchToDepartmentDTO(List<listing> e)       
    {
        List<CompanyDTO> lstCompanyDTO= e.Select(
          lstng => new CompanyDTO()
          {
            BranchId = lsting.BranchId,
            BranchName = lsting.BranchName
            DepartmentId = lsting.DepartmentId
            DepartmentName = lsting.DepartmentName
          }).ToList();
        return ListBranchToDepartmentDTO;
    }
```

Repository

```
public class CompanyRepository : IComapnyRepository
{
    public List<CompanyDTO> GetBranches()
    {
        using (TestDBEntities dbcontext1 = new TestDBEntities())
        {
            var lstCountries = from r in dbcontext1.Branches select r;
            List<CompanyDTO> lst = new List<CompanyDTO>();
            lst = CompanyBranchList.DepartmentToBranchDTO(lstCompanyDTO.ToList());
            return lst;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public List<CompanyDTO> GetDepartments(int deparmentId)
{
    using (TestDBEntities dbcontext = new TestDBEntities())
    {
        var lstDep = dbcontext.States.Where(b => b.DepartmentID == departmentId).ToList();
        List<CompanyDTO> list = new List<CompanyDTO>();
        list = CompanyBranchList.ListBranchToDepartmentDTO(lstDep.ToList());
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You define the `CompanyViewModel` constructor, and then re-assign it to an instance of itself? It should work, but that's distasteful. Better to just create it as an ordinary object.

Your bindings should not use the name of the model. The Branch binding should be simply to `Branch`, and Department to `Department`. The `optionsValue` and `optionsText` should probably not be functions. We'll need to see what the Branch and Department data look like to know exactly how it needs to be set up, but most likely they'll just be `BranchId` and `BranchName` for Branch, similar for Department.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve cascading dropdown lists by doing this:

```
// the view model bound to the view
var vm = {
   branches: ko.observableArray([]),
   selectedBranch: ko.observable(),
   departments: ko.observableArray([]),
   selectedDepartment: ko.observable()
}

// subscription to listen to changes to the selected branch
vm.selectedBranch.subscribe(function(current, last){
   if(!current) return; // do nothing if nothing is selected
   if(current == last) return; // do nothing if nothing changed

   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/api/Departments/GetDepartment/' + current.BranchId,
      contentType: 'application/json'
   })
  .then(function(result){
      vm.departments(result)
   });
}

// load the list of branches
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/api/Branches',
   contentType: 'application/json'
})
.then(function(result){
   vm.branches(result); // populate branch observable array
   ko.applyBindings(vm);// bind view model to view
});
```